# Embed Google Map in Wordpress post without using iframe or plugin?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-maps

I'd like to embed a Google Map into a WordPress post but *without* using an iframe or a plugin.

I have tried using the following HTML in the post:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 1px solid black;" width="100%" height="500px"></div>
```

But this gives me a map of zero height. I'd like to use a percentage-width map as I'm using a TwentyEleven child theme, so the site is responsive.

Can anyone suggest how I should style `map_canvas` so it doesn't collapse?

Thanks.

Comment: try not to use inline styling, not a good practice. well i just use external style and here is the result; (http://jsfiddle.net/PwKbf/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it won't work. Wordpress will strip the code out when switching from html to visual. It will only work if you leave the "html" view at all times while editing a post with the gmap code. I strongly recommend to use a plugin, like this one:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-maps-v3-shortcode/

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use the Google Maps embed code with iframe, you could use a plugin that I wrote called FitMaps. It makes a Google Maps iframe responsive, and is based on the [FitVids](http://fitvidsjs.com/) plugin for responsive video embeds.

The Fitmaps plugin wraps all Google Maps iframes in a div element and makes the iframe take up 100% width and height of this div. The wrapping div is then easily made responsive with css.

See: http://www.waywayway.nl/bin/handig-en-leuk/tutorials/responsive-google-maps-embeds/

Answer (score 0):

You can stop Wordpress 'mangling' code by doing some processing.
I put that in to a mini plugin here http://llocally.com/wordpress-plugins/?did=2

Also if you want to use MapQuest rather than Google maps there is a plugin here http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-directions/